# Turn Free Space Into Unallocated Space

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I want to expand the size of my Windows 7 Partition.  My disk is currently split into two parts, one for the OS and then one for data.  I shrunk the data partition, but it turned it into free space, which seems to be tied in the data partition somehow.  The geometry of the disk is:

100MB System Reserved| 60GB Windows| (300 somethingGB Storage|Free Space) (not sure of the size offhand)

What I want to do is turn that free space at the end into unallocated space and then add it to my Windows partition.  I don't see any option to do this in Disk Management.  I also assume the memory has to be contiguous.  Do I need a 3rd party tool to do all this or can I do it from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Download [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

You've already freed up the space.  You have one more step to add into this.  You need to move the Storage partition all the way to the end of the drive, essentially moving the unallocated space to be between the storage partition and the Windows partition.  This allows you to expand the Windows partition into the now available contiguous space.

Just noticed your comment in the other answer about UEFI.  Download and use [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) to move the partition over.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to burn a Linux live disk, boot it up and use a tool called gparted to resize the partitions. It is not possible to resize partitions while they are being used by the OS.

Here is a tutorial:
http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Comment: I've actually resized the partitions from Windows before.  I've already expanded the size of my windows part, but I wanted to add more.  Further, I can't see the partitions from Linux due to UEFI issues.

Comment: hmm i havnt run into that issue before. If your doing it from "within" windows, it does it on bootup.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted is superb!

Also interesting is the family of Easeus free products, in this case [Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm),